# Cannot import langchain.agents.load_tools

Tags: python, python-3.x, langchain

I am trying to use LangChain Agents and am unable to import load_tools.
Version: `langchain==0.0.27`

I tried these:

```
from langchain.agents import initialize_agent
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.agents import load_tools
```

shows output

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-8eb0012265d0> in <module>
      1 from langchain.agents import initialize_agent
      2 from langchain.llms import OpenAI
----> 3 from langchain.agents import load_tools

ImportError: cannot import name 'load_tools' from 'langchain.agents' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Are you sure about that version? Because they are at 0.0.93

Comment: What python version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue installing langchain with all integrations via `pip install langchain[all]`.

This installed some older langchain version and I could not even import the module `langchain.agents.load_tools` since it did not exist.

I just fixed it with a langchain upgrade to the latest version using `pip install langchain --upgrade`.

After that, I was able to import it with `from langchain.agents import load_tools` as expected.

Comment: This worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem using python 3.7.9, I downloaded python 3.10.10 instead and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

This post is 1 month old which is basically 1 year in langchain years. Alot has changed. Try updating to the latest version

```
>= to this 

langchain==0.0.134


from langchain.agents import load_tools
tool_names = [...]
llm = ...
tools = load_tools(tool_names, llm=llm)
```